# Getting variable attributes from NetCDF MFDataset in Python

Tags: python, netcdf

I am loading multiple NetCDF files in python 3 (on Windows) using `MFDataset`, and am wanting to loop through the variables and look at the attributes. I am able to load and read the data fine, however I am wanting to access the attributes associated with the variables.

```
import netCDF4
file = r"C:\netcdf_files\data*.nc" #wildcarded NetCDF files

with netCDF4.MFDataset(file) as src:       
    for name, variable in src.variables.items():            
        for attrname in variable.ncattrs():
           print("{} -- {}".format(attrname, variable.getncattr(attrname)))
```

When the above snippet runs I am given a the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 5026, in netCDF4._netCDF4._Variable.__getattr__ (netCDF4\_netCDF4.c:57060)
KeyError: 'getncattr'
```

For a single file NetCDF file, loaded with Dataset:

```
import netCDF4
file = r"C:\netcdf_files\data1.nc" #single, explicit file

with netCDF4.Dataset(file) as src:       
    for name, variable in src.variables.items():            
        for attrname in variable.ncattrs():
           print("{} -- {}".format(attrname, variable.getncattr(attrname)))
```

The above runs just fine, printing out the variable attributes as desired.

I am still very new to working with NetCDF files - is there a way to access the variable attributes when loading data using MFDataset?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code which causes the error, preferably a minimal working (or in this case, not working) example.

Comment: Hi Bart, I have updated the post with some working examples - I hope they help to explain my issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `getncattr` function is indeed not available when using `MFDataset`. This solution seems to work with both `Dataset` and `MFDataset`:

```
import netCDF4

src = netCDF4.Dataset("drycblles.1.nc")

for name, variable in src.variables.items():            
    for attrname in variable.ncattrs():
        print("{} -- {}".format(attrname, getattr(variable, attrname)))
        # or :
        #print("{} -- {}".format(attrname, variable.getncattr(attrname))) 


src = netCDF4.MFDataset("drycblles.*.nc")

for name, variable in src.variables.items():            
    for attrname in variable.ncattrs():
        print("{} -- {}".format(attrname, getattr(variable, attrname)))
```

In both cases I get the same output.